# $x_n \rightarrow x$ with respect to $d$ iff $x_n \rightarrow x$ with respect to $\rho$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm asking for proof verification on this exercise because it seemed too easy (this basically never happens for me in analysis) and that always sets off alarm bells.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $d$ and $\rho$ are two metrics on the same space $X$. Suppose that there exists a constant $C \in [1, \infty)$ such that for all $x, y \in X$,
$$C^{-1} \rho(x, y) \leq d(x, y) \leq C \rho(x,y).$$

If $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$, then $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges with respect to the metric $d$ if and only if it converges with respect to $\rho$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow x$ with respect to $d$. Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n, x) = 0$ and so
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} C^{-1} \rho(x_n, x) \leq 0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} C \rho(x_n, x)$$

Since $\rho$ is a metric on $X$, it always maps to non-negative numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. This implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} C^{-1} \rho(x_n, x) =0$. Recalling that $C \in [1, \infty)$, we can also see that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \rho(x_n, x) = 0$, proving the sequence's convergence with respect to $\rho$.

Next, suppose that $x_n \rightarrow x$ with respect to $\rho$. Then
$$0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(x_n, x) \leq 0.$$

By the squeeze principle, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(x_n, x) = 0$, and so the sequence converges with respect to $d$.

Comment: It is correct but why don't you use sqeeze theorem for the first part also? The left hand inequality is same as $\rho (x,y) \leq Cd(x,y)$.

Comment: Good point! Thank you, I think I'll do that.